# not accessing my folder or directory

Tags: c#, file-io

this program is supposed to show the path of a directory and the directory if its exists then it should also show the files inside with the following extensions (i.e .doc, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg) i created a folder called max in the bin directory the code is running but its telling me that the directory does not exist 
this is my code below

```
namespace sharp_lab_2
{
    interface IFileOperation
    {
        //should  handle the file
        bool Accept(string fileName);
        //handler function file
        void Process(string fileName);
    }

    class FileProcByExt : IFileOperation
    {
        string extName;
        string folderName;
        public FileProcByExt(string ext = "")
        {
            extName = ext;
            if (extName == "")
                folderName = "MAXee";
            else
                folderName = extName.ToUpper();
        }
        public bool Accept(string fileName)
        {
            bool res = false;
            if (extName == "" ) res = true; // all
            if (Path.GetExtension(fileName) == "." + extName) res = true; // has extension
            return res;
        }
        public void Process(string fileName)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                                                   folderName));
            File.Move(fileName,
                      Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                                   folderName,
                                   Path.GetFileName(fileName)));            
        }
    }
    class FileProcNameAfter10 : IFileOperation
    {
        static int cnt;
        public bool Accept(string fileName)
        {
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Length > 10;
        }
        public void Process(string fileName)
        {
            File.Copy(fileName,
                      Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                                   "longname_" + cnt + Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    class FileProcEnc: IFileOperation
    {
        public bool Accept(string fileName)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
            return fi.Length < 1024;
        }
        public void Process(string fileName)
        {
            File.Encrypt(fileName);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {             
                string directoryPath = args[0];
                string[] filesList, filesListTmp;
                IFileOperation[] opList = { new FileProcNameAfter10(),
                                            new FileProcEnc(),
                                            new FileProcByExt("jpeg"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("jpg"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("doc"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("pdf"),
                                            new FileProcByExt("djvu")
                                            };
                if (Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
                {
                    filesList = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                        filesListTmp = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
                        foreach (var elem in Enumerable.Except<string>(filesListTmp, filesList))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(elem);
                            foreach (var op in opList)
                            {
                                if (op.Accept(elem)) op.Process(elem);
                            }    
                        }
                        filesList = filesListTmp;
                        if (Console.KeyAvailable == true && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There is no such directory.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error." + ex.Message);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code. If you think all the code is relevant, try to reproduce the issue with minimal code, then post it.

Comment: do you are working with asp.net? Because the way to get the paste folder directoryName maybe is diferent. Are you put the correct paste address?

Comment: @MayogaX im just working with C#.net console application

Answer (score 0):

you should let your code the required permissions. 
If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the directory, the Exists method will return false.
The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file.

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)